# Trying to add a button in another support component. When adding getting an error

Tags: aem

Trying to add a button in another support component. When adding getting an error as org.apache.sling.api.resource.PersistenceException: Unable to commit changes to session.[image]

Comment: How did you add it? Can you share more details and/or stack trace from the AEM logs to get more information about the error?